# Add multiple pictures to a point

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

I am working with QGIS 3.2 (Bonn) and would like to add multiple pictures to a point (shapefile). In the end I would like to use the identify/info button and the picture should appear.
Anyone know how to do it without scripting? I am looking for an easy way to add pictures to the existing shapefile during the monitoring season, also multiple pictures

Comment: If you add a new attribute field to your attribute table using string as the type, you can afterwards edit the field in the Layer Properties -> Attributes Form. Choose "Attachment" as the Widget Type and then choose the directory, where the photos are stored. Scroll down and choose Image in the Integrated Document Viewer. You can now add photos using the attribute table. They should be displayed using the identifier tool. Perhaps you have to check "Auto open form" in the identifier. I can't test it right now so I'm not 100% sure if it works.

Comment: @gHupf please add your comment as an answer, it is detailed enough and would be more visible..

Comment: Well, I can still not add more than one picture and in the identifier results I see no picture

Answer (score 1):

Images path can be stored as text in a column. Then in properties->Display. select the field with the path. It might be required to enclose then in `<image>..</image>` tag. Then the image will show up using the identity/info button (it also works on hover mode).

A simpler way to add the image is given by @gHupf, where "*you add a new attribute field to your attribute table using string as the type, you can afterwards edit the field in the Layer Properties -> Attributes Form. Choose "Attachment" as the Widget Type and then choose the directory, where the photos are stored. Scroll down and choose Image in the Integrated Document Viewer. You can now add photos using the attribute table.*"